# detect object from video using LatentSVMDetector

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using Hog+SVM in opencv for detecting cars in Video avi file. I am using `car.xml` model file.
I am not getting good results when I used `LatentSvmDetetction` for detecting cars

- A Large number of false detections in frame.
- It is very slow. It takes about 5 seconds to detect objects from a frame.

Please suggest me how to improve object detection time.

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <dirent.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_CVCONFIG_H
#include <cvconfig.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_TBB
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static void detectAndDrawObjects( Mat& frame, LatentSvmDetector& detector, const vector<Scalar>& colors, float overlapThreshold, int numThreads )
{
    vector<LatentSvmDetector::ObjectDetection> detections;

    TickMeter tm;
    tm.start();
    detector.detect( frame, detections, overlapThreshold, numThreads);
    tm.stop();

    cout << "Detection time = " << tm.getTimeSec() << " sec" << endl;

    const vector<string> classNames = detector.getClassNames();
    CV_Assert( colors.size() == classNames.size() );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < detections.size(); i++ )
    {
        const LatentSvmDetector::ObjectDetection& od = detections[i];
        rectangle( frame, od.rect, colors[od.classID], 3 );
        putText( frame, classNames[od.classID], Point(od.rect.x+4,od.rect.y+13), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.55, colors[od.classID], 2 );
    }
}

static void readDirectory( const string& directoryName, vector<string>& filenames, bool addDirectoryName=true )
{
    filenames.clear();

#if defined(WIN32) | defined(_WIN32)
    struct _finddata_t s_file;
    string str = directoryName + "\\*.*";

    intptr_t h_file = _findfirst( str.c_str(), &s_file );
    if( h_file != static_cast<intptr_t>(-1.0) )
    {
        do
        {
            if( addDirectoryName )
                filenames.push_back(directoryName + "\\" + s_file.name);
            else
                filenames.push_back((string)s_file.name);
        }
        while( _findnext( h_file, &s_file ) == 0 );
    }
    _findclose( h_file );
#else
    DIR* dir = opendir( directoryName.c_str() );
    if( dir != NULL )
    {
        struct dirent* dent;
        while( (dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL )
        {
            if( addDirectoryName )
                filenames.push_back( directoryName + "/" + string(dent->d_name) );
            else
                filenames.push_back( string(dent->d_name) );
        }

        closedir( dir );
    }
#endif

    sort( filenames.begin(), filenames.end() );
}

int main()
{
        string frames_folder, models_folder;
        float overlapThreshold = 0.2f;
        int numThreads = -1;
        models_folder = "D:\\Downloads\\models_VOC2007";
        VideoCapture cap("D:\\images\\videos\\vid2.AVI"); // open the video file for reading
        cvNamedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
        {
            cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        LatentSvmDetector detector( models_filenames );
        if( detector.empty() )
        {
            cout << "Models cann't be loaded" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }

        vector<Scalar> colors;
        generateColors( colors, detector.getClassNames().size() );

        Mat frame;
        while(1)
        {

            bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);
            if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
            {
                cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
                break;
            }
            detectAndDrawObjects( frame, detector, colors, overlapThreshold, numThreads );
            imshow( "MyVideo", frame );
            //imshow("video", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window
              if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
              {
                cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
                break;
              }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you

1. to resize the frame to a size that 10x5 pixel is the smallest possible car in the frame;
2. to do a blur first; it is possible to get lots of false-positives because there is noise that generate edges that can be similar to the car;
3. I suppose that the detector is for side cars (I have not tested it) ant it will not detect cars rotated with more than 60 degrees and it is trained on some database that was not similar to your environment; so maybe it is better to train your own detector (car.xml).

HOG is based on edges and edges are very sensible to light and shadows. Try to preprocess (contrast enhancement) the frame before detecting the cars.